# Transferring Save Data

Tags: dont-starve

I just purchased Don't Starve and have been playing it on my Chrome browser. I've already unlocked several researches and a  new character. Is there any way to transfer this data to the Steam version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You should be able to follow these directions to import your save file:**

[**Importing save files - Don't Starve Forum**](http://forums.kleientertainment.com/showthread.php?1520-Importing-save-files)

---

Copy this URL and put it into chrome(Without quotes):

"filesystem:http://dontstarve-release.appspot.com/persistent/"

Right click on each file and save them into a folder somewhere (And remember where it is)

Open Don't Starve and choose import, Select that folder and import your save!

---

Comment: I would save it right to the desktop just to find it easily